# Azure Synapse Apache Spark to Synapse SQL connector error Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: sql-server, scala, azure, apache-spark

````
Cannot connect Azure Synapse Apache Spark to Synapse SQL


```
%%spark
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Constants
import org.apache.spark.sql.SqlAnalyticsConnector._

df.write.
option(Constants.SERVER, "servername.database.windows.net").
option(Constants.USER, "xxxx").
option(Constants.PASSWORD, "xxxx").
sqlanalytics("databasename.dbo.TableName", Constants.INTERNAL)
```
I have an error:

`Error : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException : Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'`
````

I tried to do as it is in the MS documentation and I continue with the same error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#usage

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Just from your code, you're using SQL Auth to login the SQL database. Please make sure the user  must be a member of db_exporter role in the database/SQL pool you want to transfer data to/from.

Comment: But, I cant find this role "db:exporter" any suggestions on how I should create this role on sql database?

Comment: Can you try using admin account to login the database?

Comment: I using admin account...